# Problems between selection fields dependent in Odoo

Tags: field, selection, v8, odoo

I build my first module in odoo version 8. The module definition is something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from openerp import models, fields, api, _

class class_one(models.Model):
    _name = 'class.one'
    _inherits = {'product.product': 'prod_id'} 
    _description = "First class"
    _order = "id asc"

    def _second_field_selection(self):
        query = """
        SELECT features
        FROM table_option_two
        WHERE name = 'something'
        """
        self.env.cr.execute(query)
        return [(row[0], row[0]) for row in self.env.cr.fetchall()]

    @api.one
    @api.onchange('second_f')
    def _third_field_selection(self):
        t = []
        if self.second_f:
            query = """
            SELECT cadena 
            FROM table_option_three 
            WHERE name = %s 
            """
            self.env.cr.execute(query, (self.second_f,))
            t = [(row[0], row[0]) for row in self.env.cr.fetchall()]
        return t

    prod_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Parent', required=True, ondelete='cascade', select=True, auto_join=True)
    first_f = fields.Char(string='Name', size=15, required=True, help="First field help")
    second_f = fields.Selection(string='Option_1', selection=_second_field_selection, required=True, help="Second field help")
    third_f = fields.Selection(string='Option_2', selection=_third_field_selection, required=True, help="Third field help")
    .
    .
    ...
```

Is there any way to get the values of a selection field depending on the values 
of another prior selection field?. What am I doing wrong?. (I hear suggestions).

I've noticed that if I remove the @api.onchange decorator its correctly shows the options in the second selection field in the form, but no changes captured in the first selection field.

I hope you can help me and thank you in advance. Regards

Answer (score 0):

No need to write on change method for this kind of scenario, I have changed few lines into your code. try following.

```
@api.one
def _third_field_selection(self):
    t = []
    if self.second_f:
        query = """
        SELECT cadena 
        FROM table_option_three 
        """
        self.env.cr.execute(query)
        t = [(row[0], row[0]) for row in self.env.cr.fetchall()]
    return t
```

You can simply change field in xml file add domain into the field and you will get the desire result.

```
<field name="third_f" domain="[('name','=','second_f')]" />
```